# How to communicate with service in MVVM model

Tags: android

I am developing Stopwatch application.
All stopwatch logic applied into ViewModel its works fine for forground application.
When I remove application or goes to background I want to show notification and also my stowatch should continue running.For that I try to implement forground service. 
But How to Implement this logic with Viewmodel and Service I dont know.It will be very helpful if anyone can provide information.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you would want your Service to talk to your Repository (where you get all your data from) and then your ViewModel should also be talking to your Repository so your service and viewmodel are communicating through the repository without either of them knowing the other exists. You could use something like LiveData to subscribe to events published by either the service or viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate with a service you can use an event bus (RxJava eventbus), I do not know if the ViewModel has this responsibility.

MVVM is just a presentation pattern, to create a correct architecture you should use Clean architecture, within clean architecture you have at least 3 layers: Presentation layer (In this part you use MVVM), Domain (Use cases and entities) and Data (Repository, data sources).

The data sources bring data from certain Frameworks, therefore, considering that a service is within frameworks you can retrieve the service data from data source, then call this data source from the repository, and finally to create a use case or interaction to watch this data in your view model

Frameworks ---> Data source ---> Repository ---> Use Case ---> Viewmodel

Comment: It is just an idea, however, there are cases in where you can call your frameworks layer easily. You can put your service in the ui layer(As if it were an Activity) and use live data for communication

Comment: Extend your service from LifecycleService

Comment: Thank you for this helpful information.Can you provide any refrence or example ?

Comment: To receive data from a service you can use a RxJava Eventbus (https://blog.mindorks.com/implementing-eventbus-with-rxjava-rxbus-e6c940a94bd8). But to send data from other class to the service is more difficult (Maybe use Room or shared preferences). I know that it is not the best solution but is practical.